# Location of an OutVariable in pipeline gives unexpected result

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I'm not sure if this is a simple gotcha, a bug or anything else I'm missing but I would expect following pieces of code to return the same result in the `$files.Count` outvariable.
<sub>`c:\` contains 4 files on my system.</sub>

```
gci c:\ -file -ov files | sort lastwritetime | select -first 2 | Out-Null
$files.Count # returns 4

gci c:\ -file | sort lastwritetime -ov files | select -first 2 | Out-Null
$files.Count # returns 2
```

The `select -first 2` part of the pipeline affects the `$files` variable in the second example.

---

**Edit** <sub>cudo's to PetSerAl and JosefZ for pointing me to an answer</sub>

> Sort-Object need to consume all input items to start sorting but it
>   need not to write them all to output. It can stop as soon as
>   Select-Object ask it.

*(my current understanding of things)* the output variable `$files` gets it's values from the outputstream from the `sort` command and the outputstream can stop writing if the next command asks for it.

This contrived example shows that the content of the `$files` variable changes depending on the command that follows

```
gci c:\ -file | sort -ov files | sort | select -f 1 | Out-Null;$files.count # all files
gci c:\ -file | sort -ov files        | select -f 1 | Out-Null;$files.count # 1 file
```

---

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                       
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.967                                                                                                                                                               
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                     
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                     
BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.967                                                                                                                                                              
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                             
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                         
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                         
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: i changed the names of the `-OutVariable` targets just in case they were doing something horrible to each other ... and i get the same results. if i comment out the `Select-Object` in the 2nd line of code, i get ALL of the items [36 in my test targeting `$env:temp`] - so it is the `Select-Object` that is doing SOMETHING.. ///// win7, ps5.1 ///// i have no idea what is going on ... [*blush*]

Comment: `Select-Object -First 2 -Wait`

Comment: @PetSerAl - That works but it's not expected behavior. For powershell to be able to only select two objects, it *has* to perform the `Sort-Object` first so I would have thought it safe to assume that `$allfiles` would contain all files in both situations. I'll just have to make a habit out of it to assign the OutVariable as soon as possible in the pipeline. Do you have any link that describes this behavior?

Comment: Why would you expect the same output precisely? What you're seeing is entirely logical behavour given that OutputVariable is the output of the specific commandlet, not the pipe. If you want to be sure that it's the pipe result just declare the variable with it i.e. $allfiles = gci c:\ -file | sort lastwritetime | select -first 2

Comment: @Scepticalist - The output is the same for both commands but the intermediary results stored in `allfiles` is not, *that* is the issue I'm having. As to why I use OutputVariables: it simplifies my workflow. If selecting the first two results is not sufficient, I don't have to repeat a possibly long running command to just change the selection to 3 (or more). I can just do `$allfiles | select -first 3`

Comment: There's no reason to expect that the two locations for OutputVariables would return the same result, for the very reason you allude to: The first location (Get-ChildItem) returns ALL the objects, therefore you CAN use this later on even though you normally wouldn't be able to given the rest of the pipe.

Comment: [`Select-Object` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object?view=powershell-5.0): _The Wait parameter is not required in commands that include the Sort-Object cmdlet because Sort-Object processes all objects and then returns a collection. The Select-Object optimization is available only for commands that return objects individually as they are processed._

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers `Sort-Object` need to consume all input items to start sorting. But it need not to write them all to output. It can stop as soon as `Select-Object` ask it.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Ah that makes sense. Care to write an answer for it?